# WHERE Clause 2 Different Restrictions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data, and I wanted to make a WHERE clause with 2 different restrictions applying to the same variable. I cannot figure out a way to  apply it though.

This is my current table (MINUS THE SUMMARY COLUMN THAT IS MY GOAL)

```
 ID    Location    Price     PriceDescription     SummedCost     Summary
 1     Park        -10       Cost.Water           -18            -7
 1     Park        -8        Cost.Gas
 1     Park        11        Sold.Price
 2     Tom         20        Sold.Price           -6             14
 2     Tom         -6        Cost.Soap
 3     Matt        -15       Cost.Tools           -30            -9
 3     Matt        -15       Cost.Gas
 3     Matt        21        Sold.Price
 4     College     32        Sold.Price           -22            21
 4     College     -22       Cost.Water
 4     College     11        Sold.LateFee
```

My code is

```
SELECT ID 
    ,Location
    ,Price
    ,PriceDescription
    ,SUM(Price) over(Partition by Location) AS SummedCost
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    PriceDescription LIKE 'Cost.%'
```

And this is where I run into problems. I would like to have the summary column which sums all of the prices, but I do not know how to write a WHERE statement that says the PriceDescription LIKE 'Cost.%' for the SummedCost column and PriceDescription LIKE '%.%' for the Summary column.

Is this possible? I tried to add the `WHERE PriceDescription LIKE '%.%'` to  `SUM(Price) over(Partition by Location) AS SummedCost` but I got an Error Regarding the 'as'.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please post an example of your desired outcome. I dont understand what you are asking

Comment: @GuidoG The Summary column in my table is what I want to add, its not currently in my table. You'll notice that it sums everything under the Price list for each ID, but the SummedCost column only sums the costs for each ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `WHERE` clause, and use a `CASE` expression in the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT ID 
       ,Location
       ,Price
       ,PriceDescription
       ,SUM(Case When PriceDescription Like 'Cost.%' 
                 Then Price 
                 Else 0 
            End) Over(Partition by Location) AS SummedCost
       ,SUM(Price) Over(Partition by Location) As Summary
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when as below:

```
,SUM(case when PriceDescription like 'Cost.%' then Price else 0 end) over(Partition by Location) AS SummedCost
```